# Get .NET type from Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I am working on a .NET application. In my application i have to check if the types in the assembly implement a particular interface. My assembly has a package from NuGet package (dependency) so i am using Mono.Cecil for getting all the types in the assembly. Code is:

```
ModuleDefinition module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(assemblyPath);
Collection<TypeDefinition> t1 = module.Types;
```

Issue is that Mono.Cecil return **TypeDefinition** and not **Type**. So is there anyway that i can convert each **TypeDefinition** in the collection to **.NET Type** so that i can easily check if that type implements a particular interface or not ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to use Cecil and can't use the Assembly/Type classes directly? (ie loading the assembly with Load/LoadFile and then using GetTypes, etc)

Comment: yes, i have a NuGet package installed in my assembly and in that case i cant use simple Assembly/Type Class. @pinkfloydx33

Comment: I fail to see why not. Nuget dependencies gets copied to the output directory. If you're referencing types in that assembly already it's as easy as `typeof(SomethingInNuget).Assembly` but otherwise the path will be next to your assembly so I'm confused

Comment: assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyPath)); foreach (Type t in assembly.GetExportedTypes()){} . . . . On foreach i get the exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz' . .@pinkfloydx33

Comment: Try using LoadFrom with the path to the assembly or Load with the AssemblyName (if you don't know what AssemblyName means look it up because it's not exactly what one expects off the bat). Load from a byte array appears to not be loading dependencies of the assembly (which kinda makes sense without a custom Assembly Resolve event to know where to look)

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK for you to use the full name of the interface, then you don't need `Type`, `TypeDefinition` is enough. Example (in F#):

```
let myInterface = "Elastic.Apm.Api.ITracer"

let implementsInterface (t : Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition) =
  t.HasInterfaces
  && t.Interfaces |> Seq.exists (fun i -> i.InterfaceType.FullName = myInterface)

let getTypes assemblyFileName =
  Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition
    .ReadAssembly(fileName = assemblyFileName).MainModule.Types
  |> Seq.filter implementsInterface
  |> Seq.map (fun t -> t.FullName)
  |> Seq.toArray

let ts = getTypes assemblyFile
printfn "Types implementing %s: %A" myInterface ts
// Output:
// Types implementing Elastic.Apm.Api.ITracer: [|"Elastic.Apm.Api.Tracer"|]
```

Comment: I can use the full name of the interface but i want the Type inside the assembly which implements the interface as i have to do some processing which requires Type.

Comment: Can you load that assembly via reflection? If so, you can get your type by the full name. `assembly.GetType("Your.Type.Full.Name")`